# Year on the horizontal axis (graphing with R's ggvis)

Tags: r, ggvis

I'm making graphs to be included in a Word document for publishing. I am teaching myself ggvis along the way since my (stupid?) assumption is that it is the best "environment" to make neat-looking graphs and otherwise worth investing in since you it provides "fashionable" interactive graphs also.

Everything is going fine (so far) except I can't make this histogram appear as years. Instead of 2000 it gives me 2,000.

```
require(data.table)

> head(dag)
[1] "1991-10-16" "1991-10-16" "1991-10-16" "1991-10-16" "1991-10-16" "1991-10-16"
ds %>% ggvis(~year(dag)) %>% layer_histograms(width=1, boundary=0)
```

I need at least 10 reputation to post images but maybe this link will work:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk8nb.jpg

Comment: maybe this can help: http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/ggvis/man/scale_datetime.html , change your 'dag' to a date-time scale

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. It turns out that I'm having more problems with this package, since I am unable to get non-english letters into the axis labels. So maybe I rest ggvis until I have more time to understand it. Should I delete this post or keep it as it might help others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add the formatting to your axis:

```
%>% add_axis("x", title = "Year", format = "####")
```

On a more generic matter you may consider using `ggplot` for traditional publication quality graphs. In effect, if your ambition is to produce interactive tools you will, most probably, end-up using [Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) for more advanced projects. For small demonstrations, you can employ [manipulate](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200551906-Interactive-Plotting-with-Manipulate).